# JavaScript use Java variable: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I had getted a Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier error when I use Java variable value.
The java code is :

```
    <%!String questionId = "";
  String currentUserId = "";%>
<%
    String id = request.getParameter("questionId");
    if (id != null) {
        questionId = request.getParameter("questionId");
    }
    LoginResult loginResult =     (LoginResult)request.getSession().getAttribute(I_SsoLogin.LOGINRESULT);
    currentUserId = loginResult.getUser().getUserId();
```

%>

But the variable using in JavaScript code:

```
function getAnswerAdoptView(item){

    var adoptHtml = "";
    var id = "adopt_"+item.answerid;
    var userId = <%=currentUserId%>;

}
```

in the browser show errors:**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put it inside a string like this:

```
var userId = "<%=currentUserId%>";
```

Comment: What if it is already a String ?

Comment: @ANS Clearly, javascript is not recognizing. Hence best would be to place it inside a string.

Comment: @KinshukLahiri That would fix the error but probably not achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

JSTL is not available in JavaScript resources. If you want your variable to be accessible from JavaScript you will need to declare it in a `script` tag in you HTML like:

```
<script>var userId = <%=currentUserId%></script>
```